# Make checkboxInput match the appearance of inputSlider in R shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

In the example below how I can have "Input two" match the appearance of "Input one" in terms of bolding the font and putting the label above the checkbox?

[image]

I imagine the answer is some kind of css wizardry but not sure how to approach it.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           sliderInput(inputId = "foo",label="Input one",min = 0,max = 100,value = 50,step = 10)
    ),
    column(3,
           checkboxInput(inputId = "bar",label="Input two")
    )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution could be:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           sliderInput(inputId = "foo",label="Input one",min = 0,max = 100,value = 50,step = 10)
    ),
    column(3,
           p(strong("Input two")),
           checkboxInput(inputId = "bar",label=NULL)
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yeah. I suppose that would work. Thanks.